# What are the legitimate criteria for choosing a given cost function in the implementation of gradient descent algorithm?

Tags: statistics, algorithms, regression, machine-learning

I'm working through the introductory material of a Machine Learning course (Stanford's to be precise), and notice that in [the lecture notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf) (see page 4) given by Stanford's Andrew Ng, the cost function $J(\theta)$ is defined as:

$$ J(\theta) = {1\over 2} \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2 $$

Whereas comparing this with what I've found elsewhere, in particular, [this online posting](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_numpy_batch_gradient_descent_algorithm.php) of an implementation of a batch gradient descent, by H Kong, is:

$$ J(\theta) = {1\over 2m} \sum_{i=1}^m (h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2 $$

The key difference here, is the fact that the later definition multiplies the RHS of former expression by $1\over m$.

So, given the two different definitions of the cost function - both of which claim it is the Least Squares cost function, how do I determine which one to adopt in my own work. What formal criteria are there for choosing between these two, or any other potential variations of the cost function for that matter?

Also, what's the significance of including that $1\over m$ in the later definition?

Comment: You are missing a square in your cost functions, and this matters compared with, for example, choosing an absolute value. The $\frac1m$ makes no substantial difference - either you are minimising the sum of the squares or the average of the squares, which amounts to the same thing.  The $\frac12$ makes no substantial difference either - it is just a machine learning tradition in order to remove the $2$ which appears when taking the derivative.

Comment: Some people prefer dividing by $2m$ rather than by $2$ so that the cost function is less related to the number of terms.  Personally I do not see a benefit from this, and it is an extra step

Comment: @Henry, so in essence, by what you indicate, given what the aim of the cost function is - to get us an means we'd use (the derivative) to arrive at the optimal values of our parameters, we could then discard whatever doesn't substantially enhance reaching this end? In this case, entirely do away with the constant terms in the cost function? Did I get you right?

Comment: Yes. Disposing of the $\frac1m$ or the $\frac12$ will make no difference to the analysis (so long as you carry this through to the derivative) or the optimal solution. The reason for keeping them now is solely that others use them and life is often easier if you stay consistent with others on things which do not otherwise matter.  For example, statisticians outside machine learning would typically not use the $\frac12$ in [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)  methods.